# How to mirror a Gitlab repository to make pull from AWS code-commit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-codecommit

I want to use the settings -> repository -> mirror field in gitlab to create a mirror that pulls code from aws code-commit how can i do that?

I was trying to put in the URL field something like:
**https://AWS-IAM-USER@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/AWS-CODECOMMIT-REPO**

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the settings -> repository -> mirror field in gitlab to create a mirror that pulls code from aws code-commit how can i do that?

As long as you have gitlab premium ([Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/pull.html#configure-pull-mirroring))

> I was trying to put in the URL field something like: https://AWS-IAM-USER@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/AWS-CODECOMMIT-REPO

You should be able to just use the `https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo` form of the URL.

The username and password for the IAM user should be added in the authentication part of the settings.

See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html